# Is there a workaround to submitting a form by clicking on a div without using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

This is the idea, there is a limited number of users, each has their own "box", when they click it, if they chose not to have a password they should be auto logged-in, if they do have a password a form will popup and they can type their password, click the submit button, and log in the normal way.

I know I could achieve this by using JavaScript and posting the hidden form, but then what if someone disabled JavaScript in their browser.

I could wrap the div in `<a>` tags and target another method in my controller that could use GET parameters for those auto-logins, but I do not want to use GET.

Am I missing an obvious way to achieve this? Or is there a way to use JavaScript if enabled and doing something close enough if disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each box with a form. Post the form when user click the box. On server side depending upon user need authenticated or not load the same page in client but this time with the popup(if need authentication), you can control the popup by setting a session variable in server and access it on asp page.

Not sure if this make sense .

Edit :

```
<form action="server side url " method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now use css to make the "Submit" button look like the "box" you want
So when use hit the "box" it calls the action from the form

Comment: Hm, I kind of think I understand you, but what do you mean by "post the form when user click the box"? Where would they click and how would it be posted?

Comment: like you said the user click their own box. You have to make sure the box is designed from the button.. Let me edit the post and show you

Comment: Ohhh the box IS THE BUTTON, my god that is brilliant how did I not think of that